# split html tag from string flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to split the string html with tags.

```
string :
demo <blrn-math>\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}</blrn-math>
```

expected result :

```
[demo, \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}]
```

I want to remove both the opening and closing tag

I was trying with split(). but I have no idea about regex if you guys know about then please share your answer...thanks in advance

Comment: I would recommend you take a look a this https://regexr.com/. It's easy to use and very intuitive.

Comment: @unknown please have a look at this solution

Answer (score 1):

```dart
print('demo <blrn-math>\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}</blrn-math>'.split(RegExp(r' *(<\/|<)[\w-]+> *')));
```

This outputs:

```dart
[demo, rac{-b pm sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}, ]
```

`\f` is lost when printing the string out because it's an [escaped character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character#JavaScript).

---

What the regexp  `*(<\/|<)[\w-]+> *` is matching:

1. `*` says match the character   0 or more times.
2. I used `(...)` parenthesis to create a group because inside it I'm using `|` OR.
3. `(<\/|<)` says it should start with either `</` or `<`.
4. `[\w-]+` says match more than one from `[A-Za-z0-9_]` or `-` character.
5. `>` matches, well, `>` character.
6. finally  `*` same as 1.

Answer (score 1):

you should try out this

```
  var str = "demo <blrn-math>\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}</blrn-math>";

  str = str
      .replaceAll("\f", "\\f")
      .split(new RegExp("<[^>]*blrn-math>"))
      .toString()
      .replaceAll(", ", "")
      .replaceAll("demo", "demo,");

}
```

output:

```
 [demo, \frac{-b pm sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}]
```